# C# in Linux and Mac

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

I want to run a C# (windows application) project in Linux and Mac OS.My project has a simple code, but i want to make a beautiful interface on this project.Just Mono do this work?

Comment: I'm not sure what Winforms look like on Linux, but on Mac OS it's terrible.

Comment: Consider xwt: https://github.com/mono/xwt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Mono allows you to make GUIs on Mac and Linux.  GTK# is one toolkit that will work cross-platform.  You can read more here:

http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits

Comment: but mono form is very ugly.i do not make a beautiful form on mono

Comment: "beautiful" is highly subjective.

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo They key is to make a distinction between Mono's C#/CLR implementation, and the particular UI toolkit you choose to use. For a more attractive UI, use the native toolkit, e.g. GTK# on Linux, MonoMac on OSX, etc.

Comment: With both of those toolkits you can customize your look and feel a lot.  It takes more effort though.  In my opinion, just make a web application using something like meteor.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking if you can do all this on Mono, it depends on the interface; in the general case, I doubt it. Unfortunately, Mono support is incomplete, and that doesn't look like it will change anytime soon.

Please check the following to see the status of Mono:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)#Current_status_and_roadmap

Comment: but mono form is very ugly.i do not make a beautiful form on mono

Comment: All the more reason to either not use Mono, or try your luck with a different library.  You could also try an entirely different VM with a look & feel to your liking and better cross-platform support.